# Laravel Call to Undefined Method Stripe\Plan::all()

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-5.7

This is my Laravel code but I think I might be using an older version of the Stripe function. That's why I'm getting this error, can anyone help me with this, please?

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use Stripe\Stripe;

class Plan
{
    public static function getStripePlans()
    {
        // Set the API Key
        Stripe::setApiKey(User::getStripeKey());
        try {
            // Fetch all the Plans and cache it
            return Cache::remember('stripe.plans', 60 * 24, function () {
                return \Stripe\Plan::all()->data;
            });
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a version of the Stripe-PHP library < 2.0, you'd likely need to call `Stripe_Plan::all()` instead of `\Stripe\Plan::all()`

That said, it may be helpful to upgrade to a newer version of the Stripe PHP library to take advantage of more recent features https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php